# Recursion switch return string

Tags: java, recursion

I am new to recursion and I am still confuse with this problem.

Here is the code

```
 public class TestRecursion { 
 public static void main(String[] a) { 
 System.out.println(Recurse("Yes", 1)); 
 } 

 public static String Recurse(String s, int n) { 
 if (n < 5) 
 return s+Recurse(s + n, n + 1); 
 else 
 return "End"; 
 } // end Recurse() 
}
```

so the answer for this on is:

```
YesYes1Yes12Yes123End
```

The question is **why is that the "end" prints first when I switch the return to**

```
 return Recurse(s + n, n + 1) + s;
```

notice that s is now after the recurse

Here is the result:

```
EndYes123Yes12Yes1Yes
```

Comment: Use a debugger to find out.

Comment: No need of debugger. Just grab a piece of paper and a pencil and start simulating how the method will behave.

Comment: I just did and canT figure it out it.

Comment: By the way, this is not a kind of *Java feature*. It will occur in other programming language.

Answer (score 1):

"End" is placed where the last part of the string is evaluated.  When you do `s + recurse` the last part is evaluated last. When you do `recurse + s` the start is evaluated last.

Answer (score 1):

Let's grab the virtual paper and work this out:

```
public class TestRecursion { 
  public static void main(String[] a) { 
    System.out.println(Recurse("Yes", 1)); 
  } 

  public static String Recurse(String s, int n) { 
    if (n < 5) 
      return s+Recurse(s + n, n + 1); 
    else 
     return "End"; 
  } // end Recurse() 
}
```

OK, now starting from the beginning:

```
n     S           s+Recurse(s+n, n+1)
1     Yes         "Yes" + Recurse ("Yes1", 2)
2     Yes1        "Yes1" + Recurse ("Yes12", 3)
3     Yes12       "Yes12" + Recurse ("Yes123", 4)
4     Yes123      "Yes123" + Recurse ("Yes1234", 5)
5     Yes1234     "End" <- Here we go to the else block
```

So, when we unroll the stack we get:

```
n     S           s+Recurse(s+n, n+1)
5     Yes1234     "End" <- Here we go to the else block
4     Yes123      "Yes123" + "End"
3     Yes12       "Yes12" + "Yes123End"
2     Yes1        "Yes1" + "Yes12Yes123End"
1     Yes         "Yes" + "Yes1Yes12Yes123End"
```

So, we end up with `YesYes1Yes12Yes123End`

Now, let's change the method:

```
public class TestRecursion { 
  public static void main(String[] a) { 
    System.out.println(Recurse("Yes", 1)); 
  } 

  public static String Recurse(String s, int n) { 
    if (n < 5) 
      return Recurse(s + n, n + 1) + s; 
    else 
     return "End"; 
  } // end Recurse() 
}
```

OK, now starting from the beginning:

```
n     S           Recurse(s+n, n+1) + s
1     Yes         Recurse ("Yes1", 2) + "Yes"
2     Yes1        Recurse ("Yes12", 3) + "Yes1"
3     Yes12       Recurse ("Yes123", 4) + "Yes12"
4     Yes123      Recurse ("Yes1234", 5) + "Yes123"
5     Yes1234     "End" <- Here we go to the else block
```

Now when we unroll the stack we end up with:

```
n     S           Recurse(s+n, n+1) + s
5     Yes1234     "End" <- Here we go to the else block
4     Yes123      "End" + "Yes123"
3     Yes12       "EndYes123" + "Yes12"
2     Yes1        "EndYes123Yes12" + "Yes1"
1     Yes         "EndYes123Yes12Yes1" + "Yes"
```

So, we finally get `EndYes123Yes12Yes1Yes`

Comment: Beat me by 1 minute :-) Good explanation. Maybe you need to clarify the second example a little bit more. An important implication of a recursive call placed on a return statement line is that the return statemen is evaluated firstly when the break condition is met, that is why the **recursive_call+s** prints the **End** as first -> first print the **End** string when the n < 5 is met, then evaluate the func(n+1) and the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Note that recursions can be best visualized in a tree structure (a so-called recursion tree). You generally have terminals (in your case, `s`) and non-terminals (further function calls, i.e. `Recurse`). Using draw.io (website), I quickly created this diagram for illustrating the case of `Recurse(s + n, n + 1) + s`:

[image: recursion tree]

You always evaluate from left to right. To see what happens if you switch the order of terminal and non-terminal at every step: Mirror the image vertically, and again evaluate from left to right.